# Webview is stretching to full screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-webview

I am trying to configure WebView to be placed below of ChipGroup. I am trying ContraintLayout for that but I don't exactly know what I am doing wrong because WebView is stretching to full screen, although I set `Top_toBottomOf`. Thanks

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_activity_color"
    tools:context=".presentation.activities.MainActivity">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/chip_group"
            app:chipSpacingHorizontal="15dp"
            app:singleLine="true"
            app:singleSelection="true">

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                style="@style/CustomStyleChip"
                android:id="@+id/first_chip"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/google_name" />

        </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontal_scroll_view"/>
       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: For the webview change `match_parent` to `0dp` and set a bottom constraint. `match_parent` is discouraged for _ConstraintLayout_.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Cheticamp. What do you mean by bottom constraint? I already set app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontal_scroll_view" for WebView

Comment: ooh i see   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent". Yeah thank you @Cheticamp

Comment: @Kurik9797 in case you're not sure why it happened, a height of `match_parent` literally means *"whatever the parent's height is, make this view exactly the same height"* - so you'd expect it to fill that container, right? And if there's anything else in the same container, something is gonna get overlaid on something else. With ConstraintLayout, you basically pin the various edges of a view to the edges of other views, and by pinning the top and bottom you define a space your view will live in. If you give it a fixed height, it'll be positioned in that space - a height of *0dp* will fill it

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontal_scroll_view"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add This :-**

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

code:-

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontal_scroll_view" />
```